Homemade number sequence puzzle
A homemade  number sequence puzzle. The sequence is as follows:
001, 1001, 00001, ?, 001001

The missing number is:

 10011

The pattern is:

 The i-th number of the sequence is i+1 squared written in binary and reversed.


 i = 1, 2x2 = 4 = 100, reversed gives 001

 i = 2, 3x3 = 9 = 1001, reversed gives 1001

 i = 3, 4x4 = 16 = 10000, reversed gives 00001

 i = 4, 5x5 = 25 = 11001, reversed gives 10011

 i = 5, 6x6 = 36 = 100100, reversed gives 001001

